# Laravel 5 Ajax 500 error on post using csrf token

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Been combing forums and trying everything and I'm totally stumped. Here is my form:

```
{!! Form::open(['data-regphoto', 'method' => 'POST', 'url' => ['/registerphoto']]) !!}
            <input type="hidden" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn blue" id="savebutton">Save</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

here is my ajax call:

```
$('form[data-regphoto]').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            console.log('photo pass to func: ' + data);

            var form = $(this);
            var url = form.prop('action');
            var token = $('#token').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: {'_token': token, 'photo': data },
                async: true,
                success: function() {

                    if(message) {
                        console.log('sucess: ' + data);
                        //$('.flash').html(message).fadeIn(400).delay(1200).fadeOut(600);
                    }

                }
            }); 

        });
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::post('/registerphoto', 'UserController@registerPhoto');
```

Here is my console error:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/registerphoto 500 (Internal Server Error)
n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery.js:8625
n.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:8161
(anonymous function) @ ?email=kevin5@simongjewelry.com&firstname=Test&lastname=McTest&account=4&role=admin&permissions=p1p…:374
n.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4430
n.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.js:4116
```

Comment: I am not very sure but try removing the explicitly declared hidden input, when you do {{Form::open()}} laravel automatically generated that hidden field

Comment: Shouldn't `{!! Form::open(['data-regphoto', 'method' => 'POST', 'url' => ['/registerphoto']]) !!}` be `{!! Form::open('data-regphoto', ['method' => 'POST', 'url' => ['/registerphoto']]) !!}`?

Comment: tried this still getting a 500 error returned from jquery in the console

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the meta tag in the page header like this

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Add this anywhere in your script tags

```
$.ajaxSetup
({
   headers : {'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
});
```

This should take care of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {'_token': token, 'photo': data },
            async: true,

        chunking: true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
            success: function() {

                if(message) {
                    console.log('sucess: ' + data);
                    //$('.flash').html(message).fadeIn(400).delay(1200).fadeOut(600);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please add some explanation